# How to access variables declared before try catch block in a catch block in spark scala

Tags: scala

I have defined a variable as below in my spark-scala code and try catch block.

```
var exceptionFlag = ""

try{

  exceptionFlag = "FALSE"

}
catch{
  exceptionFlag = "TRUE"
}
```

after this try catch block, I need to write the logic based on the flag.

```
if (exceptionFlag = "TRUE"){
   write the error details to hive...
}
```

The variable I defined is not able to access in catch block and so I am not able to set the flag.

Could you please suggest how to handle this situation...

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: This really is just a basic Scala programming question. Please remove the `apache-spark` flag as it doesn't apply. BTW, the code shown in the post isn't enough to indicate where or what the problem is, please make it complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ... catch is an expression in Scala, you can do the same without using a var:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  def test(): Unit ={
    val exceptionFlag = try{
      val x=10/0
      "FALSE"
    }
    catch{
      case ex: Exception=> "TRUE"
    }

    if (exceptionFlag == "TRUE"){
      println("write the error details to hive...")
    }
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

test: ()Unit

scala> test()
write the error details to hive...

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
object Driver{

  def test(): Unit ={
    var exceptionFlag = ""
    try{
      val x=10/0
      exceptionFlag = "FALSE"
    }
    catch{
      case ex: Exception=> exceptionFlag = "TRUE"
    }
    if (exceptionFlag == "TRUE"){
      println("write the error details to hive...")
    }
  }

  def main(arr:Array[String]) {
    test
  }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
write the error details to hive...
```